# How to add a global number then make it recursive in a function?

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to translate some old batch game code to Python, what I'm stuck on is adding a global number to five then make that recursive in a function.

Original Batch Code:

```
:MomsRoom
title Mommy's Roomy
set /a money=%money%+5
cls
echo You steal some money from your mom's purse.
echo Cash Money: $%money%
pause>nul
goto HOME
```

My attempt at translating it to Python:

```
def LabelMomsRoom():
    os.system('title Mommys Roomy' if os.name == 'nt' else 'pass')
    money = money+5
    cls()
    print ("You steal some money from your mom's purse.")
    print ("Cash Money:$",(money))
    pause()
    LabelHOME()
```

My expected results is that each time I visit the function a number goes up by five. My actual results are 5 to gets added to the original number, then stays at five. I've been stuck on this for a few days and need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think this would be recursive?

Comment: Global?  Easy, *don’t*.  Refactor the code to better suit a Pythonic construct.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `money` variable inside the `LabelMomsRoom()` function is local - it exists only in the scope of that function. If you have an external variable declared outside of the function and you want to reference it, you would need to use the global `keyword`. Consider this example:

```py
money = 0

def foo():
    global money
    money = money + 5
    bar()

def bar():
    global money
    money = money + 5

foo()
print(money)
```

Here, the `global` keyword for the `money` variable in the functions mean that this variable should reference a variable from outside of the function scope. You can see that in this case, the result will be 10. Note that in general, global variables are discouraged and instead you should pass the value in as a function parameter. But if you are trying to get as close as possible to the original code, maybe this could be an option.